# Django super function does't add variable to class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to make new variable in MozSerializer class using **init** to get data passed from another function. Here is code:

```
class MozSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def __init__(self, modelid, data=None):        
        self.modelid = modelid        
        super(MozSerializer, self).__init__(modelid=self.modelid)

    keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=modelid.objects.all())
    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField()
```

My goal is to pass this 'modelid' from another function to serializer(7th line...queryset=MODELID...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this would be to add the field [dynamically](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields) in `__init__`:

```
class MozSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        modelid = kwargs.pop('modelid')
        self.fields['keyword'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(\
                                             queryset=modelid.objects.all())       
        super(MozSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    pda = serializers.FloatField()
    upa = serializers.FloatField()
```

Comment: Cheers, am sure I am doing something wrong but if I leave this in MozSerializer class: keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=modelid.objects.all())

I get error that modelid is still not defined.

And when I print kwargs it returns: {'data': {'keyword': 38, u'pda': 23.67342552652728, u'upa': 12.884365610400714}}

While I was thinking it should only return model name(Url2)

Comment: From the way you were trying to use `modelid`, I understood that it is actually a model class. If this is the case, you haven't passed it in your `kwargs`. When you instantiate your serializer it sould be something like `MozSerializer(data=data, modelid=SomeModel)`.

Comment: Before I pass it, it's: type(modelid)  -  <class 'django.db.models.base.ModelBase'>

Comment: Did you remove the old `keyword = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=modelid.objects.all())`? I edited my example to include the whole class definition.

Comment: Tried both ways, if I don't remove it then it gives that 'modeild is not defined' error.

If its removed then function runs trough but it doesn't save data to model. Probably because save() function below also needs  modelid:

 def save(self):
        keyword = self.validated_data['keyword']
        pda = self.validated_data['pda']
        upa = self.validated_data['upa']
        

        modelid.objects.update(pda=pda, upa=upa)

Comment: I guess it is because I named the field `modelid` instead `keyword` in the `__init__`. I corrected the example.

Comment: The only thing this doesn't seem to do is pass modelid to save() function in serializer. Is it possible to do that from __init__ too ? Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91954/discussion-between-ivan-and-nema-ga).